# Get object data for previous frame in driver?

Tags: drivers

In blender drivers, you can access a property value on the current frame through a `var`. How can a value on a past/previous frame be accessed?

Comment: just a thought... have you tried 'var -1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a scene with an animated plane (along x-axis), and a Cube with a driver added to z-rotation the following python snippet produces the same value as the default `var` in the driver. Where the evaluate function takes the frame as parameter.

```
import bpy

for fcurve in bpy.data.objects['Cube'].animation_data.drivers:
    print(fcurve.evaluate(54))
```

[image]